# call normal javascript using angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdata

I'm trying to include legacy javascript code for affiliate tracking into an angularjs app

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[ 

        /*** Do not change ***/
        var AWIN = {};
        AWIN.Tracking = {};
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

        /*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = '{{order_total}}';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = '{(order_id}}';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = '{{cats}}';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = '';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = 'GBP';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '0';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = 'aw';
        //]]>
    </script>
```

I need to call the above code (filling in the place holders with angualr vars) and then call this:

```
    <script src="https://www.dwin1.com/xxxx.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

What is the best way to do this? I've tried placing the code into an Angular function with no success I've also tried passing the vars down into $window and trying to insert them into the CDATA at my end with no success. Any ideas?

---

I should add this code sits in a HTML page wrapped in an angualrjs controller

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? this looks not very familiar to angular's way of solving problems

Comment: From a high level, the ideal way would be to put this javascript into a directive. That's how I usually include plugins.

Comment: Your code is simple an object. Where do you need to be able to access this object from? What isn't working when you place it in your angular code?

Comment: You can have a directive with AWIN object and then when you have everything you need, you can inject script tag from that directive.  let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying is not possible directly with angularjs. you need to do something like below

```
//Note: this is a new JS file included in your main html

(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.AWIN = {};

    window.populateAwin = function(args) {
        //<![CDATA[ 

        /*** Do not change ***/
        AWIN.Tracking = {};
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

        /*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = args.order_total;
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = args.order_id;
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = args.cats;
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = '';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = 'GBP';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '0';
        AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = 'aw';
        //]]>
    }

}());
```

you then need to call this function from your controller by passing required data as shown below

```
populateAwin({
   order_total: $scope.order_total,
   order_id: $scope.order_id,
   cats: $scope.cats
});
```

Once this is done, you can proceed with inclusion of script dynamically as shown below from your controller

```
var scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
scriptEl.type = "text/javascript";
scriptEl.defer = "defer";
scriptEl.src = "https://www.dwin1.com/xxxx.js";

document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
```